# How to make a specific binding of two tables

Tags: r, dataframe, binding

I have a single column dataframe with all possible IDs:

```
ID 
a1
a2
b1
b11
c1
```

I get dataframe from my database with same column "ID". But in that dataframe, not all IDs might be. Here is example of that table:

```
ID    value
a1     18
a2     10
b1     10
```

I want to bind those tw tables in that way, so IDs which were not in my table have value zero. So, how to bind these two tables to get this:

```
ID    value
a1     18
a2     10
b1     10
b11    0
c1     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join the two tables and replace `NA` value with 0.

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, is.na(value), 0))

#   ID value
#1  a1    18
#2  a2    10
#3  b1    10
#4 b11     0
#5  c1     0
```

In base R, you can do this as :

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID', all = TRUE), 
          value = replace(value, is.na(value), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     full_join(df2, by = 'ID') %>%
     mutate(value = case_when(is.na(value) ~ 0, TRUE ~ value))
```